# Adding Magento's small_image and thumbnail Programmatically

Tags: php, magento

In Magento, the following code will programmatically add an image a product's image gallery

```
//set store to admin id so we can save a product
Mage::app()->getStore()->setId(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

//load a product with an id of 2514
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load('2514');

//add the image
$product->addImageToMediaGallery('/tmp/test.png','image',false,false);
```

This, as expected, will add an image to a product's media gallery, and this image will be selected as the product's "Base Image".  However, the "small_image" and "thumbnail" images will not be selected for this image.

If the following code is used

```
$product->addImageToMediaGallery('/tmp/test.png','image',false,false);        
$product->addImageToMediaGallery('/tmp/test.png','small_image',false,false);        
$product->addImageToMediaGallery('/tmp/test.png','thumbnail',false,false);
```

Magento will add **three** new images to the media gallery.  One with Base Image selected, one with Small Image selected, and a third with thumbnail.

Is it possible to signal Magento that when you call

```
$product->addImageToMediaGallery('/tmp/test.png','image',false,false);
```

that it should automatically generate the small image and the thumbnail image?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try with:

```
$product->addImageToMediaGallery('/tmp/test.png',array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'),false,false);
```

Comment: Strange, I have exactly this code, the image get's uploaded, but the Base Image etc are not selected... Any thoughts?

Comment: @BobvanLuijt I'm still having this issue 7 years later!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as you. The reason the image gets imported but the Media Attributes (Base, Thumbnail, Small) are not showing, is because it is being set in the Child Websites. Instead you want to set it as a Default Value. In other words the Store ID = 0.

Hope that helps.
Sam

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

**To import and set**

```
$id = 2400;
$product = $object_Manager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($id);
$imageType = ['image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'];
$imagePath = '/tmp/test.png';
$product->addImageToMediaGallery($imagePath, $imageType, false, false);
$product->setStoreId(0)->save();
```

**Just to set**

```
$id = 2400;
$product = $object_Manager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($id);
if (!$product->hasImage()) continue;
if (!$product->hasSmallImage()) $product->setSmallImage($product->getImage());
if (!$product->hasThumbnail()) $product->setThumbnail($product->getImage());
$product->setStoreId(0)->save();
```